# Regex find with two wildcards, replace one of them - TextMate

Tags: regex, textmate

I need to find and replace thousands of target urls (ahrefs) in dozens of different html documents... all of the ahrefs are formatted differently. I need to replace all of the various target urls with one uniform target url.

There are two snags:

1. I don't want to screw up the linkhrefs for css file references etc. BUt rather only change the actual ahrefs

2.in these documents there isn't a uniform structure to the ahrefs. Some have class= stuff in between the a and the href. Examples include:

```
 <a class='image' href="examplelinkone.com">
<a class='image ' href="examplelinkone.com"> ( space between e and ' )
<a class='someotherclass' href="examplelinktwo.com"
```

I can successfully FIND all instances of the ahrefs when I use regex like this...

```
<a[^<>]+href="[^<>]+"
```

...but I cant figure out how to REPLACE only what is between the double quotes of the href= part, and leave alone whatever may be between the a and the href

Comment: This is why you do not match HTML with regex. Imagine this: `<a data-smiley=">_<" href="/users">`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use capturing groups.

```
(<a[^<>]+href=")[^<>]+(")
```

In the replacement part you need to give like this,

```
$1replacement-string$2
```

`$1`  represents that we are back-referencing the characters which are present within the group index 1(`<a[^<>]+href="`). Next comes the part that was within the double quotes. This part was replaced by the string you gave as replacement string. Finally the second captured group was back-referenced to get the last `"` symbol.

Comment: some languages or tools use `\1` instead of `$1`

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this pattern should work for eliminating anything in between the quotes of `href=`:

```
\b(href=\W)[\w\s.]+(?=\W)\b
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

— Tested in TextMate:

```
 <a class="image" href="examplelinkone.com">anything<a href="more">
<a class='image ' href='examplelinkone.com'> ( space between e and ' )"<something>"All ok"</a>
<a class='someotherclass' href="examplelinktwo.com"
```

Result:

```
 <a class="image" href="">anything<a href="">
<a class='image ' href=''> ( space between e and ' )"<something>"All ok"</a>
<a class='someotherclass' href=""
```